# Using Network.requestIntercepted with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to get urls of navigation/domain redirects using the Chrome Dev tools `Network.requestIntercepted` event through Puppeteer, but I cant seem to access any of the events data.

The code below doesn't seem to trigger `Network.requestIntercepted` and I can't work out why.

Any help appreciated.

```
// console command
// node chrome-commands.js http://yahoo.com test

var url = process.argv[2];
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
const page = await browser.newPage();
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Network.enable');

await client.on('Network.requestIntercepted', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  console.log("EVENT INFO: ");
  console.log(e.interceptionId);
  console.log(e.resourceType);
  console.log(e.isNavigationRequest);
});

  await page.goto(url);
  await browser.close();
});
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that `.on()` does not return a promise, therefore you can't `await` anything.

Comment: I also use `await client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent', (e) => {
});` the same way and that works fine. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.1.1/docs/api.md#targetcreatecdpsession

Comment: @Tomalak `await` is [properly used](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession) in this example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should configure [`Network.setRequestInterception`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#method-setRequestInterception) before `Network.requestIntercepted`. Here is working example:

```
const url = 'http://yahoo.com';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch({ userDataDir: './data/' }).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await client.send('Network.enable');

  // added configuration
  await client.send('Network.setRequestInterception', {
    patterns: [{ urlPattern: '*' }],
  });

  await client.on('Network.requestIntercepted', async e => {
    console.log('EVENT INFO: ');
    console.log(e.interceptionId);
    console.log(e.resourceType);
    console.log(e.isNavigationRequest);

    // pass all network requests (not part of a question)
    await client.send('Network.continueInterceptedRequest', {
      interceptionId: e.interceptionId,
    });
  });

  await page.goto(url);
  await browser.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got it working. If I add  `if (!e.isNavigationRequest) {
     return;
    }` to `Network.requestIntercepted` it hangs though. Any idea why?

Comment: You should set `errorReason` in `continueInterceptedRequest` config object like this: `errorReason: e.isNavigationRequest ? undefined : 'Aborted'`

Comment: @turrican_34 I don't know what you are trying to achieve. But I'm sure that your code must reach `Network.continueInterceptedRequest` and returning before it can hang whole process.

Comment: Working :) Thanks for your help

Comment: It wasn't hanging straight away, but after navigation redirects where retrieved when it should have closed. Using `errorReason`, it's working fine now though.